# Scoping Dynamically Added Parent Clip

Tags: actionscript-3

I am totally flummoxed and my eyes are now spinning around in my head. I cannot seem to get this to work.

I have a movie clip that is added as a child of another movie clip. That part works fine.

I want another set of buttons to control what happens inside the newly added clip, but there must be something wrong with my dot syntax.

The button invokes this, `MovieClip(this.parent).lightHolder_mc.lightSwitcher_mc.gotoAndStop("red");`

and I get:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties. at
>   testcase_fla::controlpanel_2/makeRedClick()

I've created a ZIP/FLA that strips it down to the bare bones:
http://alphasnail.com/files/testcase.zip

Thanks x1000 to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am rather confused why this is not working (the mysteries of Flash, I guess...).

In any case, change it to:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).lightHolder_mc.getChildByName("lightSwitcher_mc").gotoAndStop("red")
```